# Add image to body of email

Tags: android, gmail, html-email

I want to add an image in email body in Android.

I have attached an image using INTENT.EXTRA_STREAM, but this is not what I want. I want it in email body.
I tried the following code, but it is not working ,can anyone give me an alternative way to achieve the task?

```
      String html="<p>This is a html-formatted string with <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i> text</p><img src=\"screenshot.jpg\"";
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,Html.fromHtml(html,
                        new ImageGetter() {

                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();

                         String imagePath = "/sdcard/screenshot.jpg";//"file://"+ base+"/"+ source;
                            Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath);
                           // bmp.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmp.getIntrinsicHeight());

                            return bmp;
                    }
                },null));
```

Comment: do you have any Errors? How is your intent created? Can you post this code too pls

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [JavaMail Api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138643.html)

[Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#IncludingImagesWithHTML) is sample code to do that,

Comment: I dont want to create a separate mail client,but i want to add images into gmail by intent method or any method that would work in this case.